# Helm - How to change the storage class used by PostgreSQL when deploying Keycloak

Tags: postgresql, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I am using the [Keycloak helm chart from **codecentric**](https://www.keycloak.org/). The chart depends on the PostgreSQL chart form **bitnami**, and by default the PostgreSQL chart uses the default storage class.

Looking [`values.yaml`](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/keycloak/values.yaml), I can see there is a section for `postgresql`, but there is no mention of the storage class. Is it possible to use Keycloak `values.yaml` file to override that setting?

The other option, that I would rather avoid, is to set `enabled: false` and deploy the PostgreSQL chart separately - hopefully that is not necessary.

```
postgresql:
  # If `true`, the Postgresql dependency is enabled
  enabled: true
  # PostgreSQL User to create
  postgresqlUsername: keycloak
  # PostgreSQL Password for the new user
  postgresqlPassword: keycloak
  # PostgreSQL Database to create
  postgresqlDatabase: keycloak
  # PostgreSQL network policy configuration
  networkPolicy:
    enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [postgres values file](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/postgresql/values.yaml) I can see that you can change the value under global.storageClass.

Since postgres is a subchart, you can either add the above to your custome values file, or pass the storage class in your helm install command, like `helm install` --set postgresql.global.storageClass="yourStorageClass"`

You can also refer to [this](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/).

Comment: Perfect, thank you for that. I had misunderstood the `globals` and had previously tried `postgresql.storageClass`, which obviously failed.